# CSS classes has no effect for svg elements

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

Thats my repro link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/svgtest?file=style.css

I applied both css classes:

```
 .section:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.section {
  transition: all 1s;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

on those svg elements:

```
render() {

    return <g className="section"
      // onMouseOver={e => this.props.currentMounting.onMountingHoveredOver(e)}
      //onMouseOut={e => this.props.currentMounting.onMountingHoveredOut(e)}
      onClick={e => this.props.currentMounting.onMountingSelected(e.currentTarget.id)}
      opacity={this.props.currentMounting.opacity}
      style={{ fill: 'red' }}
      id={this.props.currentMounting.id}>
      <rect className={"section"} x="0" y="0" height="60" width="60" />
      <rect className={"section"} x="70" y="0" height="60" width="60" />
      <text  
       className="section" x="0" y="40" fill="#000" font-size="30">Facade</text>

    </g>
  }
```

The .section class gets applied in the browser, but on hover nothing happens??

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: As the css says:"upscale the svg element when the mouse is over it"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import your CSS file into your component.

`import './style.css';`